# Boost C++ library Version Issue

Tags: c++, linux, boost

After downloading and untar the file "boost_1_56_0.tar.gz", I have installed Boost C++ library version "boost_1_56_0" in CentOS Linux.

I have run the following commands to install:

```
sudo ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
sudo ./b2 install.
```

I also added two paths to the PATH variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/include/:/usr/local/lib/
```

It has been successfully installed. However when I checked the version it showed different version:

```
$ cat /usr/include/boost/version.hpp | grep "BOOST_LIB_VERSION"

#define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_33_1"
```

I have tried to install boost_1_55_0 as well in another folder but unfortunately still it shows version 1_33_1.

Can anyone here tell me how I can fix this issue?

Because of this issue, I am unable to configure Graph_tool; it shows following error:

> checking for boostlib >= 1.53.0... configure: error: We could not detect the boost libraries (version 1.53 or higher). If you have a staged boost library (still not installed) please specify $BOOST_ROOT in your environment and do not give a PATH to --with-boost option.  If you are sure you have boost installed, then check your version number looking in . See http://randspringer.de/boost for more documentation>

Comment: your bootstrap path is to `/usr/local` but you grep in `/usr/include`. Sure you shouldn't check `/usr/local/include`? (i.e. you bootstrapped to the wrong directory?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bootstrap path is `/usr/local`. Make sure your `BOOST_ROOT` points to your bootstrapped folder, not the installed 1.33 version.

Comment: Thanks! Now version shows correctly but still when I run ./configure in order to install Graph_tool I get the following error: "checking for boostlib >= 1.53.0... configure: error: We could not detect the boost libraries (version 1.53 or higher). If you have a staged boost library (still not installed) please specify $BOOST_ROOT in your environment and do not give a PATH to --with-boost option.  If you are sure you have boost installed, then check your version number looking in <boost/version.hpp>. See http://randspringer.de/boost for more documentation"